# How to create an iterater over days in JodaTime

Tags: java, datetime, iterator, jodatime

I need to populate JComboBox with days as follows:

```
April 1, 2014
April 2, 2014
...
April 10,2014
```

I am using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html) to define dates. However, I don't know how to create an iterater over days in [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html).

```
JComboBox<String> days = new JComboBox<String>();
DateTime startD = new DateTime(2014, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0);
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  // DateTime nextD = ...
   days.addItem(startD.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")));
}
```

Comment: Your use case looks as if you rather should choose `LocalDate` not `DateTime` with zero time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DateTime currentDate = startD.plusDays(i);
```

You should have found that easily by reading [the javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusDays%28int%29).

Note that unless you really want the items to represent a precise instant (i.e. the first april at midnight in your timezone), you should probably use a LocalDate instead of a DateTime.